# Here API Batch Geocode download stream API

Tags: here-api, geocoding

we are using the batch geocode api of Here maps and when downloading the uncompressed result within a stream we want to directly reprocess the result further.

After some time (round about 18 minutes) we get a remote protocol error "peer closed connection without sending complete message body (incomplete chunked read)" (python httpx library with async client and stream.aiter_lines is used therefore a somewhat specific error message maybe).

18 minutes seems to be a strange timeout configured on here api side though, so what am I seeing here? Just a hickup? Something wrong on our side?

Thanks for any help

Comment: a subsequent run took around 5 minutes until this error so might not be a timeout at all...

Answer (score 0):

The error message "peer closed connection without sending complete message body (incomplete chunked read)" typically indicates that the server (or some intermediary) closed the connection before sending the complete response. This can happen for various reasons, and troubleshooting often requires a combination of examining server logs, client logs, and potentially any intermediaries (like proxies or load balancers).

Here are some steps and considerations to help you troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Server-side Issues**:

   - Check the server logs for any errors or warnings around the time the issue occurred.
   - Ensure that the server isn't experiencing high loads, which might cause it to terminate connections prematurely.
   - If you have control over the server, you might want to increase the logging verbosity temporarily to capture more detailed information about the issue.
2. **Timeouts**:

   - The default timeout for many HTTP clients might be too short for some operations, especially if they involve long-polling or streaming. Consider increasing the timeout on the client side.
   - Check if there's any timeout set on the server side or any intermediary (like a proxy or load balancer) that might be closing the connection.
3. **Intermediaries**:

   - If there's a proxy, load balancer, or any other intermediary between the client and server, check its logs and configurations. Sometimes, these intermediaries have their own timeout settings or might be configured to close connections under certain conditions.
4. **Keep-Alive Headers**:

   - Ensure that the server supports HTTP Keep-Alive and that it's not closing the connection prematurely.
   - If you're streaming data, consider sending periodic heartbeat or ping messages to keep the connection alive.
5. **Chunked Transfer Encoding**:

   - The error message mentions "incomplete chunked read," which suggests that the server is using chunked transfer encoding. Ensure that the server is correctly formatting the chunked response.
   - If possible, capture the raw HTTP response to see if there's an issue with the chunked encoding.
6. **Client-side Logging**:

   - Increase the logging verbosity of the `httpx` library to capture more detailed information about the request and response.
   - Consider using tools like Wireshark or tcpdump to capture the network traffic between the client and server. This can help identify if the issue is with the server closing the connection or something else.
7. **Network Issues**:

   - Intermittent network issues can cause connections to drop. Check for any network-related issues between the client and server.
   - If the client and server are on different networks or separated by the public internet, consider testing the connection over a more stable network to rule out network instability.
8. **Reproduce in a Different Environment**:

   - Try to reproduce the issue in a different environment, such as a local development machine. This can help determine if the issue is environment-specific.
9. **Library or Framework**:

   - Ensure that you're using a recent version of the `httpx` library. Sometimes, updating the library can resolve known issues.
   - Check if there are any known issues with the version of the `httpx` library you're using that might be related to this error.
10. **Test with a Different Client**:

- To determine if the issue is specific to the `httpx` library, consider testing with a different HTTP client, such as `requests` (for synchronous calls) or another asynchronous client.

If you've gone through these steps and are still facing the issue, providing more specific details about your setup, code, and the exact circumstances under which the error occurs can help narrow down the problem further.

Comment: The workaround for now has been to use response.aread() to read all the lines at once (which is somewhat missing the point of streaming but okay for now).

Would need to test if this has been an error on our side, as I am currently not sure if I did use the outputcompressed=false param correctly last time (meaning set on job trigger not when fetching)
This could indeed lead to this error.